# What is this S parameter in the Spring Data CrudRepository class?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

Can someone tell me what S is in the CrudRepository interface from org.springframework.data.repository?

I've created a class called "DBBooks" and it is the backing object for my database table "books".

> DBBooks.java

```
SNIPPET 
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="book_index")
        private Integer book_index;
        public Integer getBook_index(){
            return book_index;
        }
```

I know T is my DBBooks object and ID is the book_index key object type from my table:

```
SNIPPET 
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<DBBook, Integer> {

}
```

---

```
SNIPPET 
@NoRepositoryBean
    public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

        /**
         * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
         * entity instance completely.
         *
         * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
         * @return the saved entity will never be {@literal null}.
         */
        <S extends T> S save(S entity);

        /**
         * Saves all given entities.
         *
         * @param entities must not be {@literal null}.
         * @return the saved entities will never be {@literal null}.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
         */
        <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
```

But what is S?? I don't get it.

Comment: It means that your `Repository` class might be used to same not only instances of your `DBBook` class but all of its subclasses.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see the very similar other questions due to the <>